# select sql returning the correct result but insert based on the same select statement returns NULL

Tags: sql, azure

changed to include whole query

I am very new to SQL and having an issue with the following code. The code is looking at a table containing a total cost and a total quantity to work out the price per unit.

If I run

```
SELECT 
    ROUND(SUM(total_book / net_quantity), 6) AS per_share_book_cost 
FROM
    test_total_stock
WHERE
    net_quantity <> 0 AND total_book <> 0
GROUP BY 
    client_acc, sec_name, sec_isin, depot_name, net_quantity, total_book
```

it returns a list of

[image: example]

However if I run the following only null is returned

```
INSERT INTO test_total_stock (per_share_book_cost)
    SELECT ROUND(SUM(total_book / net_quantity), 6) AS per_share_book_cost 
    FROM test_total_stock
    WHERE net_quantity <> 0 AND total_book <> 0
    GROUP BY client_acc, sec_name, sec_isin, depot_name, net_quantity, total_book
```

[image: example]

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong please?

````
create table test_total_stock(
client_acc VARCHAR(10),
sec_name varchar(100),
sec_isin varchar(12),
depot_name varchar(50),
net_quantity decimal(20,5),
total_book decimal(20,5),
per_share_book_cost decimal(20,5)
)

INSERT into test_total_stock (client_acc, sec_name, sec_isin, depot_name, net_quantity, total_book)

Select client_acc,sec_name, sec_isin, depot_name,
    sum(case when dbt_crt = 'c' then sec_book_cost else - sec_book_cost end) as total_book,
    sum(case when dbt_crt = 'c' then sec_amount else - sec_amount end) as net_quantity

FROM test_securities_trans

group by client_acc, sec_name, sec_isin, depot_name

having sum(case when dbt_crt = 'c' then sec_amount else - sec_amount end) <> 0

order by client_acc, sec_name ASC


INSERT into test_total_stock (per_share_book_cost)
    select round(sum(total_book/net_quantity),6) as per_share_book_cost 
from 
    test_total_stock

where net_quantity <> 0 and total_book <>0
    
group by client_acc, sec_name, sec_isin, depot_name, net_quantity, total_book

```code
````

Comment: How do you identify that records? If you've selected something from table, then there was some data. So are you sure it was not null? Maybe you need to update your table with new values?

Comment: Astentx I have updated the post to show the whole query.  I am creating a new table so all data is new in the test_total_stock table

Comment: You've inserted some data and it has null in per_share_book_cost because you've omitted it in first insert. Then you calculate that values and insert new rows in table with them. So no surprise, you are still having nulls. As of [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) for `insert`: *Adds one or more rows to a table or a view in SQL Server*. You need to update your table or calculate per-share cost on the fly in the first insert

Comment: @astentx is right, you either need to UPDATE in your second statement, or just use one statement that populates per_share_book_cost in the initial INSERT. I'm pretty sure your second statement will be INSERTing extra rows with per_share_book_cost populated but everything else NULL, so it isn't returned with your filters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate the value in the same statement without moving data back and forth:

```
with calc as (
  SELECT
    client_acc,
    sec_name,
    sec_isin,
    depot_name,
    sum(case when dbt_crt = 'c' then sec_book_cost else - sec_book_cost end) as total_book,
    sum(case when dbt_crt = 'c' then sec_amount else - sec_amount end) as net_quantity
  FROM test_securities_trans
  GROUP BY
    client_acc,
    sec_name,
    sec_isin,
    depot_name
  HAVING sum(case when dbt_crt = 'c' then sec_amount else - sec_amount end) <> 0
)

INSERT INTO test_total_stock (
  client_acc,
  sec_name,
  sec_isin,
  depot_name,
  net_quantity,
  total_book,
  per_share_book_cost
)
SELECT
  client_acc,
  sec_name,
  sec_isin,
  depot_name,
  net_quantity,
  total_book,
  round(nullif(total_book, 0)/nullif(net_quantity, 0), 6) as per_share_book_cost
FROM calc
ORDER BY client_acc, sec_name ASC
```

Second `group by` does nothing because you've already grouped by that fields